# jquery ajax difference between header and beforesend

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was reading the doc on how to set headers and there are apparently two ways one is with beforesend xhr and the other is just passing a object header with values. What's the difference between them?

***beforeSend***

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', token);
    },
    success: function(data) {
         //Do something
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

***headers***

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/",
    headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //Do something
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Reviewing the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it looks like the only real difference (other than `headers` being more concise and declarative) is that `beforeSend` can override values from `headers`. From the `headers` section:

> Values in the headers setting can also be overwritten from within the `beforeSend` function.

`beforeSend` is also older than `headers`, which were added in v1.5. (I assume `beforeSend` was there prior to v1.5, since it has a note about how behavior changed as of v1.5).

Comment: Thank you. The doc can get a bit confusing. Along with most google searches saying use beforesend but my gripe with it was i couldn't pass dynamic headers to it so i wanted to know the difference.

Comment: @Darkrum: Why can't you pass dynamic headers to `beforeSend`?

Comment: How would you do that? Would you need to have a function factory? I'm not familiar with how to accomplish that. What I'm trying to do is just have 1 ajax function in my code that can be used by all other function  to make calls and pass it dynamic values i know how to do it with the headers object but how would you do it with beforesend?

Comment: @Darkrum: In that case, you'd need to have your function accept a callback that `beforeSend` calls.

Comment: Yes that's what i thought. I will stick with the headers object it seems much simpler to pass as a parameter from the calling function and have the ajax on success call back the data to the calling function and let it deal with what to do with the data. instead of having a mess of ajax calls whose only purpose it to get data and having them execute the business  logic in the success call back *shrugs uncomfortably*.